# Force page to open in html mode

Tags: pages, tinymce, dashboard

Hi I have a page that always gets messed up when opening in Visual mode, can I force this particular page to always open in HTML mode for all users in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Force html edit plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-html-edition/).